# Issue while installing grunt-critical-css

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to install

**sudo npm install grunt-critical-css --save-dev**

```
Password:**********
```

---

I kept getting

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.0.9: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN grunt-penthouse@0.3.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.2 but none was installed.
```

---

## I've tried

**sudo npm update -g npm**

```
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/lib
└── npm@3.8.7
```

**sudo npm install -g grunt-cli**

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
/usr/local/lib
└── grunt-cli@1.2.0
```

**sudo npm install grunt-critical-css --save-dev**

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.0.9: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN grunt-penthouse@0.3.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.2 but none was installed.
```

---

What did I do wrong here ? Can someone please fill in what I missed ?

---

## Detail

```
npm v3.8.7 
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1
```

---

## Gruntfile.js

```
criticalcss: {
    custom: {
        options: {
            url: "http://localhost:8888",
            width: 1200,
            height: 900,
            outputfile: "public/dist/wedding/css/critical.css",
            filename: "public/dist/wedding/css/all.css",
            buffer: 800*1024,
            ignoreConsole: false
        }
    }
},
```

Load it

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-critical-css');
```

Call it

```
 grunt.registerTask('default', [

    'clean:dist',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    // 'htmlmin',
    'compress',
    'criticalcss'

]);
```

---

## RESULT

**grunt**

```
Warning: Task "criticalcss" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

**grunt --force**

```
Warning: Task "criticalcss" not found. Used --force, continuing.
Done, but with warnings.
```

**Go check for a file**

```
Nothing generated
```

Comment: Hi @cyber8200 did you found solution? I am facing same issue. But, no any solution i found. can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

These are warning messages, usually your `npm install` will proceed successfully even if you have these messages.

These messages are generated according all the `package.json` dependency registry of the package that you are installed as well as all the hierarchical dependencies of the package you are installing.

So for example the package you are installing `grunt-critical-css` has this `package.json` https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunt-criticalcss/blob/master/package.json which for example has this dependancy `grunt-cli` that has this `package.json` https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/package.json ... and so on.

In your case one of the dependency packages, which is this `npmconf@2.0.9` has been depreciated.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix `npmconf@2.0.9 has been depreciated` error ? Please kindly advise.

Comment: is it causing a problem, other than just throwing a warning

Comment: When I run `grunt`, I got this `grunt
Warning: Task "criticalcss" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.`

Answer (score 1):

This plugin requires Grunt `~0.4.2`

Looks like you don't have correct Grunt version installed. 
Try this:

`npm update -g npm`

or

`sudo npm update -g npm`

and after that:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Okay, let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: I tried updating both, npm, and grunt, and try installing it again, `sudo npm install grunt-critical-css --save-dev` still got same error. `npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.0.9: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN grunt-penthouse@0.3.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.2 but none was installed.`

Comment: @ihue what is your current versions of nodeJS, npm, grunt? looks like everything installed successfully... it's warning messages only

Comment: I've added the details. Sorry.

Comment: @ihue try to use `grunt-critical-css` now, even if you have this warnings

Comment: Running  `grunt`, I got this `grunt
Warning: Task "criticalcss" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.` --- Meanwhile, I'll add my grunt config for that.